# Running an Mac OS command line application, how to

Tags: objective-c, command-line

Suppose you create a new `Mac OS Command Line Application` using `Xcode`, which prints something. How do you actually find and run it using your command line or Finder?

[image]

Application was "`built`", but project directory structure does not seem to contain an executable file. For what matter in what format will this file be?

Please advise

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to create iOS command line programs, at least not without jailbreaking.  Where do you see that option in Xcode?

Comment: When you create a "New Project" under "iOS", chose "Command Line Application"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the new project panel?

Comment: I misspoke earlier, I meant MAC OS command line tool, not iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help out:

1. Choose to build your project for archiving (Product->Build
   For->Archiving).
2. The executable will be created and placed in the project build
   folder. This will typically be something like
   /Users//Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Release.
3. If you wish, copy the executable to a more convenient location.
4. To run it, open up a shell window, browse to the executable
   directory, and type in your command name.

***EDIT***

I see you mentioned iOS in your question and tagged it as such. This answer is NOT relevant to iOS, infact I see no option to build a command line application for that system and it doesn't really make much sense to have one.

Comment: Is there a way to control where released code will be placed?

Comment: Yes there is, with your project open navigate to File->Project Settings. You can choose to override the location for DerivedData, or specify a whole other directory to place Builds.

Comment: Just to avoid unnecessary frustration, when running the executable from the directory it is saved in, you will probably have to type ./executablename, (notice the dot and slash, no spaces, before the executable name) depending on your path setting.